# How to setup phpUnit in Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: php, phpunit, bamboo

I am new to Atlassian Bamboo. I have my code on Atlassian Stash Repository, and I want to run PhpUnit test on my code using Bamboo plan.
I have go through documentation but I am not able to create one. Does anyone knows about it?

Comment: your question should be specific, and should be related to code where you can't solve or struggle with. see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, I agree that my question is not related to coding. Can you suggest me a better platform to ask such questions on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue myself.

Here is a proper documentation for setting Phpunit with Bamboo
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Getting+started+with+PHP+and+Bamboo

Also in order to set the PHPunit Executable path, we have to set path as: path/to/executable(phpunit folder).cmd and not just: path/to/executable(phpunit folder)
Else When you will run the build task, build will fail with error that test results were not found in required directory.